# sp_update_schedule says @schedule_id does not exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs

I wrote a script that reads job schedules from `msdb.dbo.sysschedules` and runs `sp_update_schedule` to change the `active_start_time` for a given subset of jobs. In each case, `sp_update_schedule` fails with the message "The specified @schedule_id('xxx') does not exist".  (MessageID 14262, Severity 16)

Is the `schedule id` in `sysschedules` not what it is looking for? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@schedule_id` parameter on `sp_update_schedule` does refer to the `schedule_id` column on `msdb.dbo.sysschedules`

`sp_update_schedule` contains a call to `sp_verify_schedule_identifiers` to validate the schedule, and it's from this verification step that you are getting that error (message 14262).

```
EXECUTE @retval = msdb.dbo.sp_verify_schedule_identifiers 
          @name_of_name_parameter = '@name',  
          @name_of_id_parameter   = '@schedule_id',  
          @schedule_name          = @name             OUTPUT,  
          @schedule_id            = @schedule_id      OUTPUT,  
          @owner_sid              = @cur_owner_sid    OUTPUT,  
          @orig_server_id         = NULL
```

If you are passing *both* a schedule id and a schedule name, there could be a problem in the string you are passing for the name, as that is used for additional filtering within the verification procedure.

I'd suggest doing some testing with calls directly to `sp_verify_schedule_identifiers` so that you can simplify your troubleshooting, and make sure you're passing valid parameters to `sp_update_schedule`:

```
DECLARE  
  @name_of_name_parameter   VARCHAR(60) ,--= '@schedule_name',
  @name_of_id_parameter     VARCHAR(60) = '@schedule_id',
  @schedule_name            sysname     ,--= 'syspolicy_purge_history_schedule',  
  @schedule_id              INT         = 8,  
  @owner_sid                VARBINARY(85),  
  @orig_server_id           INT,  
  @job_id_filter            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    = NULL,
  @RetCode                  INT;

EXEC @RetCode = sp_verify_schedule_identifiers 
  @name_of_name_parameter    = @name_of_name_parameter,
  @name_of_id_parameter      = @name_of_id_parameter,  
  @schedule_name             = @schedule_name,    
  @schedule_id               = @schedule_id,           
  @owner_sid                 = @owner_sid,             
  @orig_server_id            = @orig_server_id,
  @job_id_filter             = @job_id_filter;

SELECT  
   RetCode              = @RetCode,
   NameOfNameParam      = @name_of_name_parameter, 
   NameOfIdParam        = @name_of_id_parameter,  
   ScheduleName         = @schedule_name,    
   ScheduleID           = @schedule_id,
   OwnerSid             = @owner_sid,
   OrigServerID         = @orig_server_id,
   JobIDFilter          = @job_id_filter;
```

Permissions may also be getting in your way. You would need, at minimum, `GRANT EXEC ON sp_update_schedule TO <your login>` in order to make the call you are trying to make. To do the troubleshooting step I list above, you would also need to be granted `EXEC` on `sp_verify_schedule_identifiers`--though you only need this if you execute it directly. Normally, [ownership chaining](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6394/understanding-sql-server-ownership-chaining/) would allow you to only need the top-level permission & you would implicitly have the permission to do what that procedure does.  You could also be added to the `SQLAgentUserRole` security role in msdb, which includes other permissions as well--if you're rescheduling jobs, you may also need/want some of those other permissions in order to accomplish your work, assuming that this is an acceptable level of access.

Comment: I am only passing the #schedule_id and #active_start_time parameters, here is the full command being executed: "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_schedule #schedule_id=130, #active_start_time=220500" (I replaced the @ with # because Stack is complaining about notifications.)

Comment: This was very helpful. It now looks like it is a permissions issue. My code works on Localhost, where I am SA but not on the Dev server, where I believe I only have read on msdb. I'll check it out with the DBA.

Comment: @Metaphor I've updated with some comments on security for you.